# Get all values from another column in a table when null

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a bridge table in SQL and want to join back to the lookup table.

what I want to achieve here is if I join on the Hierarchy code and Base code I am getting the desired result, But I want to get all values in the lookup table for each hierarchy code where the base code is null in the bridge table.

Table format:

[image: Table format]

Comment: Please provide sample data *and expected results* as tabular text. A database tag might also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your join needs to have two predicates combined with an `OR` operator.

For example:

```
select b.*, l.*
from bridge b
join lookup l on l.hierarchy_code = b.hierarchy_code and l.base_code = b.base_code
              or b.base_code is null and l.hierarchy_code = b.hierarchy_code
```